# Integer object caching

Tags: java, caching, wrapper

I read that "So when creating an object using Integer.valueOf or directly assigning a value to an Integer within the range of -128 to 127 the same object will be returned."

This is the reason why :-

```
Integer a=100;
Integer b=100;
if(a==b) // return true as both the objects are equal
```

But why not in this below case?
These two values are also in the range of 127 and -128 so according to the statement above this two will also return the same objects.

But the output here i am getting as "Not"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer a = 10;
    Integer b = 12;
    if(a == b)
        System.out.println("same");
    else
        System.out.println("Not");
}
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: You misunderstood "the same object". It's the same object for each specific value, not the same object for all values. That would be impossible... did you really expect that `a` and `b` would refer to the same object even though the values are different? How would that object know that `a` is associated with the value 10 and `b` with the value 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what "the same object will be returned" means.

So, comparison with `==` is actually comparing memory locations, and returns true only when the two variables hold the same object (i.e. stored at the same memory location).

Values between -128 to 127 are stored in the integer constant pool, which means that every 10 is the same 10 (i.e. the same memory location), every 12 is the same 12, etc.  But it's *not* the case that all 10s are also 12s, which is what your question is unintentionally assuming.

Anyway, once you get outside of that range, each primitive int is a new object and is assigned to a new memory location outside of the constant pool.

You can test that with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer a = 1000;
    Integer b = 1000;
    if(a == b)
        System.out.println("same");
    else
        System.out.println("Not");
}
```

That will print "Not", because `a` and `b` are two different objects stored in different memory locations.

And this is why you should compare things with `.equals()`

Answer (score 1):

**==** 
  Checks whether both the references are pointing to the **same memory location.**

 In the first case **both values are same** so they are pointing to the same location  only **one object** will be created.

```java
Integer a=100;
Integer b=100;
if(a==b) // return true as both the objects are equal
```

In the second case both values are different so they have different memory location for each so **two objects** will be created.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer a = 10;
    Integer b = 12;
    if(a == b)
        System.out.println("same");
    else
        System.out.println("Not");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the actual [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)), you'll see a clearer description of what it is actually doing

> Returns an Integer instance representing the specified int value. If a new Integer instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Integer(int), as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values. This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

As the Integer returned must represent the specified int value, there is no possible way that

```
Integer a = 10;
Integer b = 12;
System.out.println((a==b));
```

will print "true", as clearly the same object couldn't represent both values.

**Edit:**

For the sake of precision - The Java standard doesn't require that Integer autoboxing (assigning a primitive `int` to an `Integer` object) uses `Integer.valueOf()`, so it is quite possible that in a conforming Java implementation

```
Integer a = 10;
Integer b = 10;
System.out.println((a==b));
```

will print "false";

Comment: Thanks i was just confused. @dan.m

Answer (score 0):

Simply They are not same object, those are two different Integer instances for to hold the given value, so as if the object are different it will always print Not